# how to make britness control work on ubuntu 14.04 with nVidia graphic card?

Tags: nvidia, brightness, nouveau

I have a Sony vaio VPCEJ equipped with an Nvidia Gforce 410m with cuda ,currently I am under ubuntu 14.04 and using the Nouveau Nvidia driver for my graphic card because I found it to be the most stable ,there is only one problem I can't get the brightness control to work ,I tried installing the proprietary Drivers but somehow the graphics quality went down so lets roll that fix from the answers :D

my question : how can I get the brightness control under Nouveau drivers ? any tweak or work around ? third party program ? any thing I am open to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WAW it was simple ,I downloaded the official Nvidia driver from [Nvidia Drivers Download](http://www.geforce.com/drivers/results/86390)
then I give it executable permission

then I closed the X-server using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>

in that command line I typed

```
./nvidia-linux-XXX.run
```

I followed the installer until it's done ,after reboot my Brightness was working just fine.